# find and change ::123:: text inside a textbox into an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm making a little smiley script for my site and i wonder how do i use jquery/javascript to find ::id:: inside a sentence inside an input box(text).

Example:
I have typed ::123:: into my text box and when i click enter jquery will find for it and get the id out of it which is 123 , then turn it into an image.

```
<input id="tb" type="text" value=""></input><input id="btn" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
<div id="display">
   image will be displayed here
   <img src="...domain/image?id=123">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var inputval = $('#tb').val();

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn').click(function(){
       //get the id from inputval(variable)
   });
});
```

P/S it will also check for if it's intergar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.replace` with a regex and group reference:

```
var strWithImgs = inputval.replace(/::(\d+)::/g, "<img src='...domain/image?id=$1'>")
$("#display").html(strWithImgs);
```

The `$1` means "the first expression in parentheses", which is the run of digits.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. I think this way is very comfortable. Cheers!

Comment: It's a regular expression that matches "2 colons, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by 2 colons"

Comment: Sure: it's a regular expression (if you're not familiar with them in general, you should learn then, as they are very handy).  The slashes indicate the start and end of the expression.  The colons are literal colons, and the slash-d means "a digit".  The plus sign means "one or more".  So the whole thing means "one or more digits between some colons".  The "g" at the end means "so this for all matching patterns in the string, not just once".

Comment: Will do , apsillers , i will look up for it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('#tb').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
         var value = this.value.replace(/::/g, '');
        if(jQuery.isNumeric( value )){
            $(this).next().find('img').attr('src' , "...domain/image?id="+value)
        }
    }
});
```

this means thatif the user press <kbd>return</kbd> the value inside the textfield will be parsed, and after removing the `::`, if it's a number will be used for the src of the img

Comment: what if there are other text with the ::123:: id? like "hello ::123::" , if you do this it will get "hello 123"

Comment: @sm21guy i thought that in that case the value wasn't a number and it wasn't ok, sorry if i misunderstood your question